# Send full url with query string to file in mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to catch every request that comes in on my domain name and redirect that url to a php file. In this PHP file I show a form and when the user passes the form I want to redirect the user to the page it requested orignally.

I've got the following mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(accepts_cookie) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) test.php?link=.. [L]
```

As you see I would like to place the full requested url in the link= but how am I able to do this? I tried stuff like: REQUEST_URI, but that doesn't give me the full path including query strings.

I hope someone can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(accepts_cookie) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test.php?link=%{REQUEST_URI}%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

</IfModule>
```

You can always consider the [mod_rewrite Cheat Sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Though when I use this solution and I go to the following url: index.php?request=lol&test=lol it indeed redirects me to test.php, but the $_GET['link'] is only index.php without the query strings.

Comment: Hmm still doesn't seem to work @Havelock for some reason $_GET['link'] is just test.php now.

Comment: Almost.. when I go to: hello.php?test1=1&test2=2
I get this output: /sjaak.phplink=/hello.phptest1=1

Comment: So you don't get the rest after the `&`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12211/discussion-between-havelock-and-mittchel)

Comment: You can try adding `B` flag after the `L`

Comment: Not working for the second parameter with B flag. :-(